# Comparing Group Means with Chi-Squared

Tags: r, chi-squared

I would like to see if differences in groups means within my data are statistically significant.

How do I run a chi-squared test with data in a long format like this

```
Country        Year     Value
Country A       1         2
Country A       2         3
Country A       3         3
Country B       1         6
Country B       2         7
Country B       3         6
Country C       1         9
Country C       2         8
Country C       3         9
```

I do not know how to run the chi-squared test on the same variable but for different groups (countries).

Thanks

Comment: What is the "Value" column the value of?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reformat your data from the long format into the appropriate wide format for most statistical tests like this. I like the `reshape2` package to help with these sorts of things.

For example:

```
> x <- read.table(text = "Country        Year     Value
+ Country.A       1         2
+ Country.A       2         3
+ Country.A       3         3
+ Country.B       1         6
+ Country.B       2         7
+ Country.B       3         6
+ Country.C       1         9
+ Country.C       2         8
+ Country.C       3         9", header = TRUE)
> 
> 
> library(reshape2)
> wide <- dcast(x, Country ~ Year, value.var = "Value")
> wide
    Country 1 2 3
1 Country.A 2 3 3
2 Country.B 6 7 6
3 Country.C 9 8 9
```

Now it's closer to the format you need for a `chisq.test()` or any other test you may be interested in running. The first row contains the Country column which most likely needs to be excluded from the analysis since it is not pertinent to the counts:

```
> wide[, -1]
  1 2 3
1 2 3 3
2 6 7 6
3 9 8 9
```

I'll leave it up to you to determine what test is appropriate for your data.

Comment: I think further thought ought to be applied to the assumptions of independence and the type of measurement. The R `chisq.test` is designed for counts. Do we know that these are counts? What hypothesis are you testing?

Comment: @Dwin - fair enough, I probably should have just stopped after the reorganizing of the data from long to wide...not sure what they are after here or what we're looking at...

Comment: I am looking for ways to compare groups means on the same variable and to demonstrate that the different means are statistically significant.

My data has 67 countries, with multiple observations (10-15) for each country. I would like to find a way to show that the mean Value for the different countries are statistically meaningful.

Comment: So far, I have run three different OLS regressions to try and show this. First, I ran a regression of the Value on 66 country dummy variables. This can show that the coefficients on many of the country dummies are statistically significant and different from the base country. Second, I created a dummy variable that takes the value of 1 for all countries with above median GDP. This can show that the different in mean Value between the 'poor' and 'wealthy' countries is statistically different.

Comment: I also wanted to run a chi-squared test, which should tell me if any of the group means are significantly different than the pooled mean (a pretty low bar). However, I could not figure out how to run a chi squared test on data in the following long format.

Comment: I think you need to post this on http://stats.stackexchange.com ... your 'regression' was essentially a one-way ANOVA, now I think you're looking for either (1) setting "sum-to-zero" contrasts (so that the parameters of your regressions are the differences of all but one country from the overall mean) or (2) preferably, doing a post-hoc multiple comparison test (see `glht` in the `multcomp` package)

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified a hypothesis to be tested, so apply a "chi-squared test" is not yet possible. (The fact that you specify a particular case about which you are uncertain as to implementation suggest his might be homework.)  It is reasonably clear from the data you offer that the rows are not at all independent. You only have three countries and then repeated measures over sequential time intervals of something that has integer values. Are those counts? If this is an effort to simplify a richer dataset for discussion purposes, then you need to amend your question and put in some effort at construction of a realistinc test case, so that substantive comments can be offered

Comment: I suppose it is as much of an answer as is warranted. With an incomplete question, sometimes all you can offer is an incomplete answer.

Comment: Not a big deal, but I would say that in this case *no* answer (i.e. only comments) are warranted, until the question is completed ...